# Issue with Android SQLite: 'No such column' error

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm making the app that stores a list of the user's purchases in a SQLite database in android. A problem I'm having is I can't delete any of the entries. This is the error message I am getting: `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: purchaseId (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM purchases WHERE purchaseId='0'`.  It's not finding the purchaseId column.  What can I do?

here's my relevant code:

In this function I store a list of the database contents in an arraylist called purchaseList. Then I iterate through all of items, passing the id to my deletePurchase method:

```
public void clearHistory(){
        purchaseList = dbTools.getAllPurchases();
        int size = purchaseList.size();
        for(int id = 0; id < size; id++) {
            String idString = String.valueOf(id);
            dbTools.deletePurchase(idString);

        }

    }
```

In this function I create the database. purchaseId is an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, which autoincrements:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE purchases ( purchaseId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, datePurchased TEXT, " +
                "storeName TEXT, price TEXT)";


        database.execSQL(query);
}
```

This function is where I think the problem is. I know purchaseId is an integer, but is this line correct: `String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM purchases WHERE purchaseId='"+ id +"'";`?

```
public void deletePurchase(String id) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

        String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM purchases WHERE purchaseId='"+ id +"'";   //***line of interest***
        database.execSQL(deleteQuery);

    }
```

I think there is an easy fix because the deleteQuery works if I use another column like storeName, which is a STRING

Any help?

Comment: try this.. "DELETE FROM purchases WHERE purchaseId='+ id +'";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this:
for integer type ' are not necessary.

```
String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM purchases WHERE purchaseId="+ id ;
```

Comment: Still getting similar error: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: purchaseId (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM purchases WHERE purchaseId=0

Comment: once uninstall and run the application, and auto increment starts from 1

Answer (score 1):

try this remove `single quote(')`

```
  String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM purchases WHERE purchaseId="+ id; //Remove single quote
```

Your `purchaseId` column type is integer.

Comment: I am getting a similar error unfortunately: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: purchaseId (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM purchases WHERE purchaseId=0